# Unexpected implicit conversion from nlohmann::json to string

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

While debugging an application I came up with the following example:

```cpp
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using nlohmann::json;
struct X {
    X(const std::string& s){}
};
int main() {
    X x("{}"_json); // why compiler allows this?
}
```

See at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ser6KG3zc)

Could someone explain this?
Is this a bug or an unexpected side effect of nlohmann/json library?

---

Update:

... and here is the second question:

As implicit to_string conversion is a documented feature, then is this a bug that this even simpler example fails at runtime?

```cpp
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
using nlohmann::json;
int main() {
  std::string j = "{}"_json;  
}
```

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::type_error'
what():  [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be string, but is object

Comment: It's a documented feature: use `operator string` to search in the API docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up API docs here: https://github.com/nlohmann/json/search?q=operator+string

You'll find that `operator string_t()` is a documented feature of the library to convert `json_pointer` to `string_t`. This conversion is considered when you call the ctor of `X` with an argument type that's not the listed argument type (`const std::string&`) and likely succeeds (to the extent that it can be compiled).

Comment: That operator is deprecated though, but it as [`operator ValueType ()`](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/operator_ValueType/) that may play a role here. Edit: Hmm, nope, that doesn't seem to be it either...

Comment: Another question then why this implicit conversion fails ? (See error at Godbolt link)

Comment: Basically event just this line will compile and then fail at runtime: std::string j = "{}"_json;